# why regular expression .*? only match an empty string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, non-greedy

```
/.*?/.exec("abc");//output [""]
```

I think `.*?` is non-greedy and it should return `a`

Comment: If you want just one character, you can use 
`/./.exec('abc')`
without any modifiers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well that is expected since `.*` means 0 or more and by putting `?` you make it non-greedy hence it match an empty string.

If you want to match `a` then you should use:

```
 /.+?/.exec("abc");
```

DIfference is `+` instead of `*` which means match 1 or more characters using non-greedy quantifier.

Comment: but there is no empty char in `abc`. you mean it also can match a position like `^ $ \b` ?

Comment: Yes it definitely can. In this case it is just matching `^`

Comment: can you please show me some articles about `.*` match a position? it's  a little weird.

Comment: Better to go through this post: http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html

Comment: @looping: `/b*a/.exec("abc")`

Comment: @looping Think of it in this way. /a(b*)c/ should obviously match "ac", what does the capturing group (b*) capture?

Answer (score 0):

By using `*` instead of e.g. `+` you allowed for matching empty string as a non-greedy option.